# How to remove 0 from a string using sed

Tags: regex, string, sed, substitution

I have string *"001.036.020"* and I need to convert it to *"1.36.20"*.
Saying other words I need to remove all "0" before digit. Is it possible to do this using sed?

Comment: As much as I hate to be the one who says it...what have you tried so far?

Comment: why do you want to do that!Isn't that unnecessary..

Comment: This is a version number. I want to convert it as described above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sed should work:

```
sed 's/0*\([1-9]\)/\1/g'
```

**EDIT:** To handle more complex cases like:

- 0s in between digits:
- handle a segment with only 0s (would be collapsed to a single zero)

On Linux:

```
sed -r -e 's/(^|\.)0+([1-9])/\1\2/g' -e 's/(^|\.)(0)0*(\.|$)/\1\2\3/g'
```

OR on Mac:

```
sed -E -e 's/(^|\.)0+([1-9])/\1\2/g' -e 's/(^|\.)(0)0*(\.|$)/\1\2\3/g'
```

Comment: One more thing. It does not work if I have 001.036.200. Result should be 1.36.200

Comment: This removes zeroes between other digits, e.g. `001.306.020` becomes `1.36.20`. It also does not handle a segment with only zeroes (which I assume should be collapsed to a single zero)?

Comment: hammer you are right. Only zero should collapse to a single zero

Comment: @user1209304: Provided another edit to handle 0s in between digit cases. IMO it is better to list out all the cases in the questions upfront so that an answer can address all of them.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '001.036.020' | sed 's/^0*//'
```

Comment: That won't work as it will output `1.036.020` instead of expected `1.36.20`

Comment: Oups, This one works: `echo '001.036.020' | sed -e 's/\.0*/./g' -e 's/^0*//'`